# Obtener el nombre de las carpetas y el link del archivo contenido en ella desde carpeta padre

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

Tengo algunas películas organizadas de la siguiente manera.

PELÍCULAS/spider man (2020)/spiderman-2020-sd-eng.mp4

Quiero que la siguiente información se extraiga en una hoja de cálculo.

| ** nombre ** | ** enlace ** |
| --- | --- |
| spiderman (2020) | enlace de la película mp4 |

Dónde:
** spiderman (2020) **: es el nombre de la carpeta donde se encuentra la película
** enlace de película mp4 **: es el enlace de película spiderman-2020-sd-eng.mp4

El código que tengo extrae el nombre de la * carpeta *, pero también extrae el * enlace * de la carpeta ... (me gustaría que extraiga el nombre de la carpeta y el enlace de la película).

resultado del código que tengo:

```
// replace your-folder below with the folder for which you want a listing
function listFolderContents() {

  var foldersID = DriveApp.getFolderById("10Zw76wu2UNz3jufimUFGd8OJErPGnsih");
  var foldername = foldersID.getName();
  var folderlisting = 'listado de ' + foldername;
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFolders();

  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name','link'] );
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

podrias ayudarme...?

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el resultado deseado de varias carpetas deberías aplicar el siguiente código:

```
  function ReadCarpeta(){  
  //DEFINO LA CARPETA RAIZ, PARA ESTE CASO "PELICULAS"
  const FolderRoot = "xxxx";
  //OBTENGO TODAS LAS CARPETAS DE ESA CARPETA RAIZ
  const Folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderRoot).getFolders();
  let arrayResult = []
  let peliculas;

    while (Folders.hasNext()) {
        //OBTENGO LA CARPETA DENTRO
        let carpeta = Folders.next();
        //OBTENGO EL NOMBRE DE ESA CARPETA
        let nameFolder = carpeta.getName(); 
        // OBTENGO LOS ARCHIVOS CON CIERTO MIMETYPE (Para garantirazar que sea una pelicula "video/mp4")    
        // ESTO ES PARA GARANTIZAR QUE SOLAMENTE OBTENGA EL LINK DE LAS PELICULAS
        // PARA ESTE EJEMPLO UTILIZO IMAGENES/PNG
        peliculas = carpeta.getFilesByType("image/png");
        //RECORRO TODAS LOS ARCHIVOS CON ESE MIMETYPE
          while (peliculas.hasNext()) {
            //OBTENGO LA PELICULA
            let peli = peliculas.next();
            //OBTENGO EL LINK DE LA PELICULA
            let linkArchivo = peli.getDownloadUrl().replace('download', 'view');
            //LOS INTRODUSCO EN UN ARRAY PARA LUEGO UTILIZARLO
            arrayResult.push([nameFolder,linkArchivo]);
          };
    }
Logger.log(arrayResult)
//.. QUEDA AGREGAR EL ARRAYRESULT AL GOOGLE SHEET A LA HOJA DE CALCULO
}
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias amigo, por tu gran ayuda

Comment: @AbdiasRiveraBautista Si es la respuesta que necesitabas, te invito a marcarla como respondida